"A porta dormiu aberta", "a televisão dormiu ligada" e "a comida dormiu fora da geladeira"
Nos sambemos que portas, aparelhos de televisão, e alimentos não dormem, mas essas expressões são usadas com frequência em minha região do sudeste brasileiro. Em relação a esse uso do verbo dormir, eu pergunto:

É só um regionalismo ou seria compreendido por qualquer falante da língua portuguesa?
No caso, trata-se de uma figura de linguagem que significa "pernoitar", "passar a noite".  Qual é a figura de linguagem?


Pode ser personificação, mas vejo mais como uma metáfora. Parecida com "as crianças não param de latir lá fora", em que "latir" expressa "gritam/berram como um cachorro late". Assim, "dormir" seria "passam a noite como alguém dorme".

Creio que o uso é tão estabelecido, que não se trata de uma figura de linguagem, mas de um significado regular de "dormir": passar a noite. Também não há indicação de que se trate de um regionalismo:

Infopédia:


dormir verbo transitivo
3. passar a noite em


Aulete:


dormir verbo
7. Passar a noite em (algum lugar) (falando-se de algo). [ta.: O carro dormiu na rua.]


É tão usado que o Aulete tem uma entrada para esse significado?! Eis a resposta aqui!
